# How to add Release Notes file path reference in nuspec file

Tags: c#, nuspec

I'm working on a solution which has several projects. Each project has it's own release notes.I need to specify path of the release notes in the specific project's nuspec file. How do I achieve that?.. If I just add file path it doesn't seem to work. Could you please help.

This is how my nuspec file looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package >
      <metadata>
        <id>Test Framework</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>Test Team</authors>
        <description>Test nuget Package</description>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency id="NUnit" version="2.6.4" />
          <dependency id="Nancy.Hosting.Self" version="0.23.1" />
          <dependency id="System.IO.Abstractions" version="1.4.0.86" />
        </dependencies>
      </metadata>
      <files>
          <!--Dlls for NugetPackage-->
         <file src="\TestBase\bin\$BuildConfig$\TestBase.dll" target="lib\net46"/>
 <file src="\TestBase\Docs\ReleaseNotes.doc" target="lib\net46"/>
        <file>
      </files>
    </package>
```

Comment: The path to the file must be relative to the folder that the .nuspec file is in. So is the TestBase folder immediately below the nuspec file? Also you don't need the first backslash, and I don't think that the target attribute will have any relevance for document files, so you could drop it if you want.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file must be relative to the folder that the .nuspec file is in. So is the TestBase folder immediately below the nuspec file? Also you don't need the first backslash, and I don't think that the target attribute will have any relevance for document files, so you could drop it if you want.